# How to display row counts for queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view, count

Funny issue because it seems the query is simple compared to other stuff I have and I know the answer but not how to display it as one view.

So I have 2 tables

Table A
uid
firstname
lastname

Table B
uid
firstname
lastname

I do an inner join on uid to show how many of the records that these two tables share and I can see the rows but can't output the row count right in a view.  Would simply like to see:

In Both - 4500

Not in Table B - 13000

With the numbers being the number of unique uid (they are already unique in each table) for each of the two described queries.

Comment: inner joins can't tell you how many mis-matched records there are, because inner joins will only EVER return records that exist in both tables.

Comment: @MarcB - Can't I take total rows in A minus the unique matches?

Comment: I think Marc's clue there is "INNER joins can't tell you..."

Answer (score 0):

The first would be

```
SELECT count(a.uid)
FROM a inner join b on a.uid = b.uid
```

The second one is

```
SELECT count(b.uid)
FROM a left join b on a.uid = b.uid 
WHERE b.uid IS NULL
```

Comment: I get zero for the second query when it should be total row count in A minus first query - which works.  Also how do I display both in the same view?